# как автомонтировать ntfs в линуксах

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Мучаюсь с тем, чтобы сделать автомонтирование ntfs дисков при запуске системы.
В интернете куча примеров, как это сделать и все они прекрасно работают. Но при этом проявляются побочные эффекты , если не один - то другой.

1. Файлы теряют возможность удаляться в корзину (можно только удалить начисто).
2. Всякие текстовые файлы при клике по ним пытаются запуститься в терминале(т.к. походу все по умолчанию на диске стало исполняемым).
3. 1ый и 2ой вариант вместе взятые.

Раньше мне помогала такая конфигурация автомонтирования:

```
UUID=(здесь мой UUD) /media/disk-e ntfs-3g defaults,umask=007,gid=46,uid=1000 0 0
```

Теперь после переустановки системы, она почему-то не работает. 
Посоветуйте, как прописать параметры монтирование правильно.

Answer (score 1):

За корзину не скажу, а вот такая версия конфига в ''fstab'' отлично работает на версиях ntfs, которые лежат в ubuntu 12.04 и 14.04:

```
UUID=111111111111 /windows/c ntfs-3g users,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8 0 0
```

Comment: попробовал эту конфигу. Тестовые файлы при клике пытаются запуститься в терминале еще и удаляются мимо корзины только.

Comment: Про корзину не обещал, а вот на счёт терминала - не знаю. У меня на компе с которого пишу - именно такая строка и даблклик открывает именно gedit. Попробуй перезагрузи комп.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74199/trash-on-ntfs-for-multiple-users-why-does-dolphin-succeed-where-nautilus-fails вот ещё нашёл

Comment: в первом предложенном варианте файлы нормально запускались, но не удалялись в корзину (я ошибся когда написал, что запускаются в терминале) .
А по ссылке, оба конфига из ответа не работают, во втором даже создавать новые файлы нельзя.