# После монтирования не открывается диск

Tags: ubuntu

> Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ruben/Project: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ruben/Project"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
>   Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Операция не позволена
>
> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>   Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

После того, как попытался смонтировать второй жесткий диск, внес изменения fstab, но потом какая-то ошибка возникла, решил вернуть обратно, и удалил то, что я внес в fstab. После этого даже вручную теперь не открывается. Что делать?

Comment: перезагрузиться под виндой, проверить диск, и перегрузиться назад под линукс

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Can't Mount NTFS drive "The disk contains an unclean file system"](http://askubuntu.com/q/462381/3712)

Comment: @KoVadim проблема в том, что у меня нет винды, я ее удалил. Только убунту стоит. В таком случаи как быть?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs && man ntfsfix`

Comment: @kff эта команда не помогает

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584280/191416 ; http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497159/191416 не?

Comment: @ra.chobanyan "не помогает" не информативно. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и приведите точные команды и что они выводят и что вы ожидали вместо этого. 2- можете ли как read-only подключить? (как показано по приведённым ссылкам)